# Visual Studio does not generate client proxy code when adding service reference

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, visual-studio-2013, workflow-foundation

I have a WF [Workflow Foundation] project and when I try adding a service reference [Visual Studio 2013-Target Framework is 4.5.1] to it the generated reference code doesn't contain the client proxy code. I tried adding a service reference to other non WF projects [Library projects] and it works fine and the reference.cs contains the Client proxy code. Why Visual Studio doesn't generate client proxy for WF projects? If the facility is not there then obviously I am taking the wrong approach. How can I use a WCF method inside my CodeActivity?

Just to remind you that this is not the duplicate of the following thread :
[Service reference not generating client types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000209/service-reference-not-generating-client-types)

Comment: In fact that's exactly what I wanted to do but every time I tried to do it I was given an error saying a question with the same title has been posted already. I was pressing the Answer you Question button for your information.

Comment: I don't think an answer exists with the same title (at least I can't find it), it must be a bug. Try changing it to a slightly different title. When you use the "Answer your own question" checkbox, you're given two text areas: one for the question and another for the answer.

Comment: I had to change the title as you said and now it works and I answered my own question. Thanks for mentioning though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a simple Reference.cs file Visual Studio kindly adds 7 more files to the service reference folder. When I recompile the project and build it all the methods of my WCF service appeared on the toolbox [and became available] and now I can use them in my Work Flows.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution you found for your own problem, but you forgot to mark it answered!